# Select statement in CASE condition

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, case

.I have the following code

```
 SELECT BRCODE,PRCODE,SHORTNAME,SUM(NVL(CUMSALE,0)-NVL(CUMCRD,0)) NETSALE,SUM(CUMTAR) TRGT,ROUND(SUM(NVL(CUMSALE,0)-NVL(CUMCRD,0))/SUM(CUMTAR)*100,2) ACH 
case
when regexp_like(:lprdate, 'OCT' ) = 'OCT' then
select statement for OCT
when regexp_like(:lprdate, 'NOV' ) = 'NOV' then
select statement for NOV
when regexp_like(:lprdate, 'JAN' ) = 'DEC' then
select statement for DEC
ELSE
SELECT BRCODE,PRCODE,SHORTNAME,SUM(NVL(CUMSALE,0)-NVL(CUMCRD,0)) NETSALE,SUM(CUMTAR) TRGT,ROUND(SUM(NVL(CUMSALE,0)-NVL(CUMCRD,0))/SUM(CUMTAR)*100,2) ACH 
FROM ANALYSIS1 WHERE LASTRPTDT1 = :lprdate1 GROUP BY BRCODE,PRCODE,SHORTNAME  order by BRCODE,PRCODE
END
```

Here :lprdate and :lprdate1 are user inputs fired while generating reports.
User may input Oct , Nov ,Dec for :lprdate and Jan for :lprdate1 .
will this case statement help in providing the results according to the codnitions given in case statement?

For example if I give :lprdate = '31-OCT-17' , will this go in the first case statemnt? 
Please help.
No i haven't tried the code due to some technical issues with the software. If i get to know whether this solution is working, I would be happy to execute quickly

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Why aren't you just waiting until you can try it?

Comment: If I had any thing similar to this I might have understood the results. I couldn't find any hence. and time is a constraint for me

Comment: Why are you using `like` on something that is ostensibly a `date` column?

Comment: There are many issues with the statement as presented but you should really just run what you have when the database is available and then update the post with the results.

Comment: there is no END CASE statement in your code and what does this statement for 'select statement for OCT'? what is its purpose after THEN clause?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
select monthname, somenumber, sometext
from
( select 'OCT' as monthname, 123 as somenumber, 'Demo for October' as sometext from dual
  union all
  select 'NOV' as monthname, 456 as somenumber, 'Demo for November' as sometext from dual
  union all
  select 'DEC' as monthname, 789 as somenumber, 'Demo for December' as sometext from dual
)
where  monthname = :param;
```